# MongoDB: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14

Tags: mongodb

I run MongoDB on Mac:

```
Shave:mongodb_simple Logan$ ./bin/mongod -f conf/mongod.conf
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 5110
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 14
```

Is that because I shutdown it in wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you haven't configured your `mongod` instance correctly in the config file that you passed to the `-f` option.
Revisit your config file and make sure eveything is configured correctly.

Comment: Uhh this is my mongo.conf: `port = 12345
dbpath = data
logpath = log/mongod.log
fork = true`

Comment: @Luster Looks like you didn't write it in YAML [http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/] format. is that the case?

Comment: when i got this error it was because my `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` file was owned by `root`.  even the `-v` option didn't help solve it.  i wound up removing ALL my config file info so it used the default and _THEN_ it finally gave me the right error message.

Comment: A possible can be if one of the listening sockets is wrong, e.g. if it's configured to bind to `::1` even if IPv6 is disabled, in the log files in e.g. `var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` you would then find a line similar to _"Cannot assign requested address for socket"_.

Comment: I quote @icfantv 's reply

Comment: In my case, it was because `root` owned some of the files in `/var/lib/mongo`

Comment: "WiredTiger.turtle" was owned by root.. half an hour wasted :)

Answer (score 15):

You started and probably shutdown mongo in the wrong way.

**1. TO START MONGODB**

To start mongo  in the background type: `mongod --dbpath /data/db --fork --logpath /dev/null`.

- `/data/db` is the location of the db. If you haven't created one yet => type: `mkdir /data/db`
- `--fork` means you want to start mongo in the background - deamon.
- `--logpath /dev/null` means you don't want to log - you can change that by replacing `/dev/null` to a path like `/var/log/mongo.log`

**2. TO SHUTDOWN MONGODB**

Connect to your mongo by typing: `mongo` and then `use admin` and `db.shutdownServer()`. Like explain in [mongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

If this technique doesn't work for some reason you can always kill the process.

1. Find the mongodb process `PID` by typing: `lsof -i:27017` assuming your mongodb is running on port 27017
2. Type `kill <PID>`, replace `<PID>` by the value you found the previous command.

Comment: Yes, this was my case, I was running a virtual machine and then my laptop froze abruptly. Since I was just creating a couple of tests I got rid of the whole data folder.

Answer (score 14):

Check the ownership of the file `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`

It should be `mongod`. I got same error since it was `root:root`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For me it worked a bit different, I changed the ownership to my **user** and it started working for me.

Comment: Wow incredible this just happened to me on a fresh install, 5 days out of the blue after installation. I wonder what causes it? And it will happen again on service restart?

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue, too. This situation can arise if you start `mongod` as user `root` directly on the `CLI`, instead of issuing, say, `systemctl start mongod`, which will start things as `mongod`.

Comment: This works for me. Does anyone know the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 5):

For me it was `ulimit` issue, mongo could not open too many files.

Used `ulimit -n 10000`.

However as a generic pointer look into mongo logs file, they will tell where to look further. Generally the logs file are in `/var/log/mongo.log` but look into your mongo config file.

Answer (score 4):

By changing owner to `mongodb` for all files under `/var/lib/mongodb/` it started working for me:

```
chown mongodb:mongodb -R /var/lib/mongodb/
```

Comment: For more recent versions: chown mongod:mongod -R /var/lib/mongod

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

run in terminal

```
sudo rm -rf mongod.lock
export LC_ALL=C
```

then

```
sudo mongod --fork --config /xxxx/xx/mongod.conf --logpath /xxx/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```

Answer (score 2):

with me I remove file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
then restart mongod

Answer (score 2):

Just run this and start mongod

```
rm -f /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock

systemctl start mongod
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the mongod is running with `pgrep mongod` or `ps -aef | grep mongod` or `systemctl status mongod`

Stop and restart it to check if the issue gone
if you start mongod with `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf` kill it with `pkill -9 mongod`  then start it with `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf`
fi you run it a service, use `systemctl restart mongod` to restart it.

If restart not works, figure out the issue by the `/var/log/message` and `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` file.
use `tail -f /var/log/message` and `tail -f /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` to check the output when your action.

```
for example:
    1.
        Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Operation not permitted
            delete the sock file with `rm`
    
    
    2.
        WiredTiger error (13) [1596090168:830936][25997:0x7fe22f208b80], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 672: /data/mongo/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied Raw: [1596090168:830936][25997:0x7fe22f208b80], wiredtiger_open: __posix_open_file, 672: /data/mongo/WiredTiger.turtle: handle-open: open: Permission denied
        Failed to start up WiredTiger under any compatibility version
        Reason: 13: Permission denied
        
            check the file permission or owner with `ls` then change to the wright permission with `chmod` or right owner with `chown`
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but mine was the system clock being off so my SSL cert was technically invalid. Changing to the current date and time worked `date --set "<DD M Y H:M>"`
 Only found this by looking at the mongodb log

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue on a GCP managed Compute Engine instance.
As this is the top answer on a Google search for the issue, I'll include what worked for me, and is a documented bug as per MongoDB ([jira-link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9032))

> On linux systems, if the user running mongod does not have a locale set or the locale is misconfigured, mongod fails to start printing a stack trace.

The issue can be resolved by combining a few steps:

1. Install the required language packs ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/408726)):

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-XX
```

2. Run update locale ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/76106)):

```
sudo update-locale
```

3. Restart your session, and check the same mongo command again
4. IFF the above doesn't work (it didn't for me), just manually add the following to the file at `/etc/default/locale` ([ref](https://askubuntu.com/a/229512/155158)):

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

5. Just to admire the absence of those persistent warnings about LC_ALL not being set, run the following:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

That's all, your MongoDB instance should be good to go now!

Answer (score 0):

In my mongodb setup, in order to retain a specific version of mongoDB inline to existing servers and also to avoid having binary files placed under root disk, i changed the path of all mongo binaries in a different directory. i had to use `rpm` option instead of `yum` option (*as yum installs only the latest version despite of mentioning the specific version*).

```
rpm -ivh --prefix=/apps/mongodb /apps/mongo_rpm_packages/mongodb-org-*.rpm
```

**Note:** The default path where the binaries will be placed is `/var/lib/mongo`.

This approach does not either allow required permission for `mongod` user or its not provisioned properly and hence, i changed `user` and `group` in `mongod.service` file to `root` user and managed to successful start the process using:

```
service start mongod
```

Answer (score 0):

Use --shutdown

```
mongod --shutdown
```

Then

```
service mongod restart
```

It work!

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#use-shutdown

Answer (score 0):

1. you may have already running mongodb instance, from "mongosh"  shutdown it gracefully with a command db.shutdownServer()
2. check your log file if you have error in mongod.conf
3. in mongod.conf file set "fork: false" where you can see the error directly during the starting process.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).