# ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 48

Tags: mongodb

error 48 is a new error for me.

i'm also getting the error when trying to enter mongo

```
Error: network error while attempting to run command 'isMaster' on host '127.0.0.1:27017'

v3.2.10
git version: 79d9b3ab5ce20f51c272b4411202710a082d0317
allocator: tcmalloc
modules: none
build environment:
  distmod: ubuntu1604
  distarch: x86_64
  target_arch: x86_64
```

i try starting mongo with

```
sudo mongod --fork --port 27017 --replSet replset --logpath ~/log/mongo.log
```

Comment: Refer to this [SO: MongoDB: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63167528/6521116)

Answer (score 15):

just kill the mongod process first

```
ps -ef | grep mongod
sudo kill -9 {processid}
```

then run the command.

Answer (score 6):

What does the log file says? This error usually comes when there is a process already running with the port number you are using to start mongod process with, which is 27017 here.

You can run the below command to check the spid which is using the port

netstat -ntulp|grep 27017

Answer (score 3):

I took used to get similar error (error no. 48). I usually run like this:

```
mongod --config /apps/data/appdb/appdb.conf --fork
```

In my "appdb.conf" there is a parameter called "Bind Address" which was pointing to "0.0.0.0" and I simply changed it to actual IP of the server/machine (which can be found if you run **hostname -i** command). Saved the file and tried the above "fork" command and worked like a charm. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for the first answer, you should not kill a Mongodb process with -9.

See use kill section in following documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/

Maybe try to find and delete `mongod.pid` (/your/path/mongodb/mongod.pid) and restart Mongodb again.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following steps to restart the process:

1. `pidof mongod`
2. `sudo kill -9 {pidOfRunningMongod}`
3. `sudo mongod --fork --auth --port 27018 --dbpath /data/db --logpath /var/log/mongod.log`

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

On ec2, do not use the public ip in the list of bindip. It allows mongod to listen to incoming requests not just from the localhost. You have to use the private IP.
You should be able to connect from within your network using the private IP.

Answer (score -1):

reverting the bind_ip to 127.0.0.1 in the /etc/mongod.conf is working.