# MongoDB cannot start with fork?

Tags: mongodb, fork

I have a mongod.conf which contains

```
processManagement:
    fork: true
```

However when I run `mongod --config ./conf/mongod.conf` it gave me the error as following:

```
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 48
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
error Command failed with exit code 48.
```

Also when I start Mongodb with `mongod --fork --logpath=./mongo.log` it also gave me error as following:

```
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
```

It seems like I cannot start Mongodb with --fork option. How can I fix this problem? **How can I set up Mongodb with my mongod.conf ?**

BTW my Mongodb version is v4.0.4. Really appreciate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 48](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113266/error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-48)

Comment: but the solution in that post cannot solve my problem.

Comment: I think there you have a few different problems. 
In the first situation you are trying to use a port which is already in use (the other MongoDB process is running or this port is taken by other program). In the second situation you have the permissions problem (take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963147/install-mongodb-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-100).

Answer (score 0):

Please check your configuration file. Double check all directory such as logpath, dbpath, pidfilepath,... 
If you run by mongod user, make sure your directories own by that user.

Answer (score 0):

mongod creates a socket file in tmp dir which can cause an error while restarting with different.
Check the /tmp directory or logs file for mongo.