# Docker mongo:6.0.5 image is not able to start using docker-compose with even default config given in official example

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I am trying to run [mongodb 6.0.5](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) using [docker-compose v1.25.0](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) by following official exmaple given at https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo on [Kubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu) Linux.

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo:6.0.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
```

I am trying to run using command `sudo docker-compose up mongodb`
Here is the output

```bash
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cf3xxx:~/backend$ sudo docker-compose up mongodb
Recreating backend_mongodb_1 ... done
Attaching to backend_mongodb_1
mongodb_1               | about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
mongodb_1               | forked process: 28
mongodb_1               | 
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.425+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.426+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.426+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.429+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.430+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.430+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.430+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.430+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.431+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information\n"}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.431+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"std::exception::what(): Operation not permitted\nActual exception type: std::system_error\n\n"}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"main","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"558454F486A4","b":"558450136000","o":"4E126A4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"},{"a":"558454F4ABE9","b":"558450136000","o":"4E14BE9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"},{"a":"558454F44F37","b":"558450136000","o":"4E0EF37","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"},{"a":"5584550CF9C6","b":"558450136000","o":"4F999C6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"},{"a":"5584550CFA01","b":"558450136000","o":"4F99A01","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"},{"a":"5584550CFB3B","b":"558450136000","o":"4F99B3B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"},{"a":"55845204B737","b":"558450136000","o":"1F15737","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"},{"a":"5584550EBD39","b":"558450136000","o":"4FB5D39","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"},{"a":"558452FFED8A","b":"558450136000","o":"2EC8D8A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"},{"a":"55845225D63E","b":"558450136000","o":"212763E","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B4E"},{"a":"55845204C46E","b":"558450136000","o":"1F1646E","s":"main","s+":"E"},{"a":"7F8950328D90","b":"7F89502FF000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"},{"a":"7F8950328E40","b":"7F89502FF000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"},{"a":"558452257F25","b":"558450136000","o":"2121F25","s":"_start","s+":"25"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"6.0.5","gitVersion":"c9a99c120371d4d4c52cbb15dac34a36ce8d3b1d","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"5.4.0-144-generic","version":"#161-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 3 14:49:04 UTC 2023","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"558450136000","elfType":3,"buildId":"3C976B679319B912CD7F7AC36B539DCD7F937343"},{"b":"7F89502FF000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"69389D485A9793DBE873F0EA2C93E02EFAA9AA3D"}]}}},"tags":[]}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558454F486A4","b":"558450136000","o":"4E126A4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558454F4ABE9","b":"558450136000","o":"4E14BE9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558454F44F37","b":"558450136000","o":"4E0EF37","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"5584550CF9C6","b":"558450136000","o":"4F999C6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"5584550CFA01","b":"558450136000","o":"4F99A01","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"5584550CFB3B","b":"558450136000","o":"4F99B3B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"55845204B737","b":"558450136000","o":"1F15737","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"5584550EBD39","b":"558450136000","o":"4FB5D39","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558452FFED8A","b":"558450136000","o":"2EC8D8A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"55845225D63E","b":"558450136000","o":"212763E","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B4E"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"55845204C46E","b":"558450136000","o":"1F1646E","s":"main","s+":"E"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F8950328D90","b":"7F89502FF000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7F8950328E40","b":"7F89502FF000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"}}}
mongodb_1               | {"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T05:48:00.501+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558452257F25","b":"558450136000","o":"2121F25","s":"_start","s+":"25"}}}
mongodb_1               | ERROR: child process failed, exited with 51
mongodb_1               | To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cf3xxx:~/backend$
```

I tried running mongo:6.0.5 image via docker also using command below. But that is also not working.

```bash
sudo docker run --name some-mongo mongo:6.0.5
```

Output is

```bash
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cf3xxx:/tmp$ sudo docker run --name some-mongo mongo:6.0.5                                       
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.723+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.724+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.725+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.726+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.726+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.726+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.726+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.726+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.726+00:00"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6384300, "ctx":"main","msg":"Writing fatal message","attr":{"message":"std::exception::what(): Operation not permitted\nActual exception type: std::system_error\n\n"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31380,   "ctx":"main","msg":"BACKTRACE","attr":{"bt":{"backtrace":[{"a":"558868E876A4","b":"558864075000","o":"4E126A4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"},{"a":"558868E89BE9","b":"558864075000","o":"4E14BE9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"},{"a":"558868E83F37","b":"558864075000","o":"4E0EF37","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"},{"a":"55886900E9C6","b":"558864075000","o":"4F999C6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"},{"a":"55886900EA01","b":"558864075000","o":"4F99A01","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"},{"a":"55886900EB3B","b":"558864075000","o":"4F99B3B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"},{"a":"558865F8A737","b":"558864075000","o":"1F15737","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"},{"a":"55886902AD39","b":"558864075000","o":"4FB5D39","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"},{"a":"558866F3DD8A","b":"558864075000","o":"2EC8D8A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"},{"a":"55886619C63E","b":"558864075000","o":"212763E","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B4E"},{"a":"558865F8B46E","b":"558864075000","o":"1F1646E","s":"main","s+":"E"},{"a":"7FD066584D90","b":"7FD06655B000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"},{"a":"7FD066584E40","b":"7FD06655B000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"},{"a":"558866196F25","b":"558864075000","o":"2121F25","s":"_start","s+":"25"}],"processInfo":{"mongodbVersion":"6.0.5","gitVersion":"c9a99c120371d4d4c52cbb15dac34a36ce8d3b1d","compiledModules":[],"uname":{"sysname":"Linux","release":"5.4.0-144-generic","version":"#161-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 3 14:49:04 UTC 2023","machine":"x86_64"},"somap":[{"b":"558864075000","elfType":3,"buildId":"3C976B679319B912CD7F7AC36B539DCD7F937343"},{"b":"7FD06655B000","path":"/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6","elfType":3,"buildId":"69389D485A9793DBE873F0EA2C93E02EFAA9AA3D"}]}}},"tags":[]}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558868E876A4","b":"558864075000","o":"4E126A4","s":"_ZN5mongo18stack_trace_detail12_GLOBAL__N_119printStackTraceImplERKNS1_7OptionsEPNS_14StackTraceSinkE.constprop.362","C":"mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::printStackTraceImpl(mongo::stack_trace_detail::(anonymous namespace)::Options const&, mongo::StackTraceSink*) [clone .constprop.362]","s+":"1F4"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558868E89BE9","b":"558864075000","o":"4E14BE9","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceEv","C":"mongo::printStackTrace()","s+":"29"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558868E83F37","b":"558864075000","o":"4E0EF37","s":"_ZN5mongo12_GLOBAL__N_111myTerminateEv","C":"mongo::(anonymous namespace)::myTerminate()","s+":"D7"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"55886900E9C6","b":"558864075000","o":"4F999C6","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE","C":"__cxxabiv1::__terminate(void (*)())","s+":"6"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"55886900EA01","b":"558864075000","o":"4F99A01","s":"_ZSt9terminatev","C":"std::terminate()","s+":"11"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"55886900EB3B","b":"558864075000","o":"4F99B3B","s":"__cxa_throw","s+":"4B"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558865F8A737","b":"558864075000","o":"1F15737","s":"_ZSt20__throw_system_errori.cold.24","C":"std::__throw_system_error(int) [clone .cold.24]","s+":"2F"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"55886902AD39","b":"558864075000","o":"4FB5D39","s":"_ZNSt6thread15_M_start_threadESt10unique_ptrINS_6_StateESt14default_deleteIS1_EEPFvvE","C":"std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())","s+":"29"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558866F3DD8A","b":"558864075000","o":"2EC8D8A","s":"_ZN5mongo27startSignalProcessingThreadENS_13LogFileStatusE","C":"mongo::startSignalProcessingThread(mongo::LogFileStatus)","s+":"11A"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"55886619C63E","b":"558864075000","o":"212763E","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongod_mainEiPPc","C":"mongo::mongod_main(int, char**)","s+":"B4E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558865F8B46E","b":"558864075000","o":"1F1646E","s":"main","s+":"E"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FD066584D90","b":"7FD06655B000","o":"29D90","s":"__libc_init_first","s+":"90"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"7FD066584E40","b":"7FD06655B000","o":"29E40","s":"__libc_start_main","s+":"80"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-05-11T09:10:59.807+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":31445,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Frame","attr":{"frame":{"a":"558866196F25","b":"558864075000","o":"2121F25","s":"_start","s+":"25"}}}
alok@alok-HP-Laptop-14s-cf3xxx:/tmp$
```

What is wrong with my config so mongodb is not able to start?

I carefully looked into existing such question [Mongodb ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 51](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54759516/mongodb-error-child-process-failed-exited-with-error-number-51) and its answers. They are not relevant to me as I am not passing any custom config file nor I am trying to mount volumes. My question is not related to even existing data of old mongodb. So please dont mark my question as duplicate.

Comment: Did you have a look as [Install MongoDB Community with Docker](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-community-with-docker/)?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: I did not followed that.

Comment: This exact compose file works for me. Is there a reason you are using the standalone `docker-compose` vs. the built-in `docker compose`? What is `docker-compose version` and `docker version`? Is this in WSL? What happens if you run `docker compose down && docker compose up`?

Comment: docker-compose v1.25.0 on Kubuntu 20.04 Linux.

Comment: Is the `mongod` log file writable? I.e., its directory exists and the server has write permission?

Comment: Maybe you should better follow the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: @rickhg12hs: everything is happening inside conrainer so there should not be any issue of permission. Even there are not mount of volumes so its clean config.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: offical is also not working for me. I tried running `sudo docker run --name some-mongo mongodb/mongodb-community-server:6.0.5-ubuntu2204`. its giving error `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['mongod', '--bind_ip_all']' died with <Signals.SIGABRT: 6>`

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading `docker 20.10.5` fix this problem.

Comment: I met the same issue on docker 18.06.1-ce, but the same command works well on docker 25.0.2. Did you find the root cause?